# Can you convert a Rails app to Sinatra on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sinatra

Does anyone know if there is any issues with converting a Rails app to Sinatra with Heroku? I already have a Heroku app running and it is currently a simple Rails app that is basically a few views and a controller with no database interaction. Are there any potential issues if I just change everything from Rails to Sinatra?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There shouldn't be any issues, other than the manual work required by you. You'll want to make sure and update your `Procfile` to run your Sinatra app correctly. See here for [Deploying Rack-based Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack) on Heroku's Devcenter. I also recommend using Foreman for local development, it should helping to find any possible issues running on Heroku easier: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#developing-locally-with-foreman

Comment: Foreman will use configuration variables declared in a `.env` file locally, much like how Heroku will use the configuration variables stored in `Heroku config`. By storing things that are likely to differ between production/development in configs, your code base is simpler and you'll have fewer surprises deploying between the two.